# Does shared randomness between two cryptographic primitives complicate the hybrid argument for computational indistinguishability?

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation

Let $(Enc, Dec)$ be an IND-CPA secure encryption scheme, where $Enc: \mathcal{K} \times \mathcal{M}_1 \rightarrow \mathcal{C}_1$, and $F: \mathcal{K} \times \mathcal{M}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{C}_2$ be a pseudorandom function.

Consider a simple example where we may want to prove the distribution $(Enc_k(m_1), F_k(m_2))$ (whose randomness comes from the **shared key** $k \leftarrow \mathcal{K}$) is computationally indistinguishable from the uniform distribution on $\mathcal{C}_1 \times \mathcal{C}_2$. Clearly, we can show that the distribution of $Enc_k(m_1)$ is computationally indistinguishable from the uniform distribution on $\mathcal{C}_1$ via a reduction to IND-CPA security. By replacing $Enc_k(m_1)$ with a random element $r_1 \leftarrow \mathcal{C}_1$, we can obtain an intermediate hybrid $(r_1, F_k(m_2))$. My question is that:

**Can we then apply the pseudorandomness of $F$ to replace $F_k(m_2)$ with another random element $r_2 \leftarrow \mathcal{C}_2$, in order to prove the above computational indistinguishability?**

From my perspective, the two random variables $Enc_k(m_1)$ and $F_k(m_2)$ are **not** independent since they share the same randomness $k$. This is reminiscent of the reason why we should consider the joint distribution of someone's view-output tuple rather than its view in secure computation. So, I suppose that the shared randomness here does prevent a simple hybrid argument from going through. Is this conclusion right? Many thanks.

Comment: Can we always have the guarantee that $\mathcal C_1 \times \mathcal C_2$ is indistinguishable from random? Wouldn't it be easy for an attacker to distinguish $\mathcal C_1$ if the encryption is some counter-based mode?

Comment: @MarcIlunga, I think that IND-CPA security ensures that the output of $Enc$ should be pseudorandom as long as key space $\mathcal{K}$ has enough entropy, say, $\kappa$ bits.

Comment: Ï am not sure CPA  can *always* give that guarantee. A pathological example: modify a CPA scheme to append a $0$. i.e. $ctxt = c|0$ . This remains CPA secure but is distinguishable from random. A better example would be the CTR mode of operation with nonces. so $ctxt = n | c$. I think also distinguishable from random if $n$ is a counter and not randomized.

Comment: The original question on shared randomness is still intersting tho: )

Comment: @MarcIlunga, thank you for your comment. A formal definition of IND-CPA is indeed missing in my question. Here, I informally use the term "IND-CPA" to refer to the property that an encryption scheme can result in pseudorandom ciphertexts in $\mathcal{C}_1$.

Comment: I would suggest to explicitly add this version of CPA in the question explicitly. It’s worth noting that this is not the standard CPA notion and seems like too strong of a requirement. The CTR example has a proof for standard CPA but doesn’t satisfy this non standard CPA notion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

> A formal definition of IND-CPA is indeed missing in my question. Here, I informally use the term "IND-CPA" to refer to the property that an encryption scheme can result in pseudorandom ciphertexts in $\mathcal{C}_1$

This is of course a stronger assumption than being IND-CPA, but it is boring to point this out.
Really, this assumption can be written as

> $\mathsf{Enc}_k$ is a PRF family.

It is perhaps more straightforward to think about this in terms of PRFs, so I will quickly show that if $F_k, G_k$ are (individually) PRFs, then $(F_k, G_k)$ need not be, e.g. sharing PRF keys can break security.
This is because of the dependence between the left and right components, as you have guessed.

Let $F_k$ be a PRF, and let $G_k = F_k^{\circ 2}$, i.e. $G_k(x) = F_k(F_k(x))$.
It is simple to see that $G_k$ is (individually) a PRF --- any distinguisher for it implies a distinguisher for $F_k$, as you can efficiently emulate query access to $G_k$ given query access to $F_k$.

Now, $(F_k, F_k^{\circ 2})$ is not a PRF.
This is because, given an oracle $\mathcal{O}(\cdot)$ that is either real or random, you can.

1. $(y_1, y_2)\gets \mathcal{O}(x)$,
2. $(z_1, z_2) \gets \mathcal{O}(y_1)$,
3. guess REAL if $y_2 = z_1$, and RANDOM otherwise.

IF $\mathcal{O}(x) = (F_k(x), F_k^{\circ 2}(x))$ is your PRF, then $y_2 = F_k^{\circ 2}(x)$, and $z_1 = F_k(y_1)= F_k(F_k(x)) = F_k^{\circ 2}(x)$ collide.
In the random game, the probability of any two values colliding is quite small, so this immediately implies a rather good distinguisher.

There are more immediate problems though.
One way to build $\mathsf{Enc}_k(m)$ is by XORing $m$ with a PRF, for example $\mathsf{Enc}_k(m) = (r, F_k(r)\oplus m)$.
This is simply randomized counter mode (where messages are a single block).
In this setting, the joint construction is $(m_1,m_2)\mapsto (r, F_k(r)\oplus m_1, F_k(m_2))$.
Again, by querying on $(m_1, m_2)$, and then querying $(m_3, r)$, one can obtain an efficient distinguisher.
This is to say a natural construction (where $\mathsf{Enc}$ is randomized counter mode) is not secure in your setting as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed example!

Comment: or simply $F=G$

Comment: @Mikero that is actually a much more interesting example, as it shows that $F, G$ being PRFs individually is not enough to show that $(F, G)$ is even a "weak PRF", meaning an adversary can distinguish $(F_k(x), G_k(x))$ from random even if $x$ is randomly chosen, rather than adversarial chosen. I was unable to show this using my examples in my answer.